# Aspas dentro de aspas e novamente dentro de outras aspas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho uma variável string chamada [Conteudo] e quero atribuir a ela a tag de um botão que chama um javascript. Estou tentando assim:

```
        Conteudo = "<input id='btnOculta_" + lin + "' type='button' value='novo' class='btn btn-default' onclick='Ocultar(this, 'OcultaNovoMedicamento_1')' style='float:left' />"
```

Porém no trecho *onclick='Ocultar(this, 'OcultaNovoMedicamento_1')'* ele está entendo a segunda ' como um encerramento da primeira e não como uma segunda abertura. E me retorna um código todo errado.

**Esperado:**

```
<input id="btnOculta_1" type="button" value="novo" class="btn btn-default" onclick="Ocultar(this, 'OcultaNovoMedicamento_1')" style="float:left" />
```

**Obtido (errado):**

```
<input class="btn btn-default" id="btnOculta_1" style="float:left"         onclick="Ocultar(this, " type="button" value="novo" ocultanovomedicamento_1')'="">
```

uComo resolvo esse pepino?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Podes usar `\` para *escapar* essas aspas e fazer assim:

```
onclick='Ocultar(this, \"OcultaNovoMedicamento_1\")'
```

Exemplo:

```js
var lin = 2;
var Conteudo = "<input id='btnOculta_" + lin + "' type='button' value='novo' class='btn btn-default' onclick='Ocultar(this, \"OcultaNovoMedicamento_1\")' style='float:left' />";

document.body.innerHTML += Conteudo;

function Ocultar(el, txt) {
  console.log(el.tagName, txt);
}
```

Em browsers modernos, ou se estiveres a transpilar, podes usar template strings assim:

```
Conteudo = `<input id='btnOculta_${lin}' type='button' value='novo' class='btn btn-default' onclick='Ocultar(this, "OcultaNovoMedicamento_1")' style='float:left' />`
```

Comment: Valew @Sergio a sua primeira sugestão usando \ não funcionou... não sei s eporque teste correndo aqui, rsrs. Mas a segunda funcionou muito bem! Obrigado, me salvou aqui. No seu exemplo só tem uma aspas duplas sobrando no fim, mas ok.

Comment: @AlamBique corrigi, assim ficam os dois exemplos sem bugs :)

Answer (score 1):

Tenta usar aspas duplas com escape em OcultaNovoMedicamento_1:

```
Conteudo = "<input id='btnOculta_'  type='button' value='novo' class='btn btn-default' onclick='Ocultar(this, \"OcultaNovoMedicamento_1\")' style='float:left' />"
```

Comment: Obrigado @italo este metodo tem uma compatibilidade maior com browsers antigos né? Muito bom! Cara onde vocês aprendem esses segredos? kkkkk!